# How to increase size of heat map built using seaborn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, heatmap

Below is the code to show the sentence similarity in a heat map. The final graph is a nxn matrix where each entry [i, j] is colored based on the inner product of the encodings for sentence i and j.

```py
def plot_similarity(labels, features, rotation):
  corr = np.inner(features, features)
  sns.set(font_scale=1.2)
  g = sns.heatmap(
      corr,
      xticklabels=labels,
      yticklabels=labels,
      vmin=0,
      vmax=1,
      cmap="YlOrRd")
  g.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=rotation)
  g.set_title("Semantic Textual Similarity")

def run_and_plot(messages_):
  message_embeddings_ = embed(messages_)
  plot_similarity(messages_, message_embeddings_, 90)
```

The heatmap works fine, however as the number of message increase, the results are no more visible. Is there a way to  zoom the heatmap? Or the size increases based on the number of entries?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out a way to increase the size of my plot with the following single code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplots(figsize=(20,15))
```